# angular.js @local scope property coming as undefined if we initialized as null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have made custom angular directive

```
 <location zipcode="35423" cityname="" statecode=""></location>
```

and take

```
  scope: {
                    zipcode: "@",
                    cityname: "@",
                    statecode: "@"
                },
```

in contoller of that directive :

```
 controller: function ($scope, $filter) {
$scope.zipcode = "35423" // here i get the values
$scope.cityname = undefined // ?? why?
$scope.statecode= undefined // ?? why?
}
```

i want `$scope.cityname = ""`

in reality i am using mvc application

```
zipcode="@ZipCode" cityname="@City" statecode="@StateCode"
```

and it might possible that `City` could be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of the scope properties to `""` if they're undefined like so: `$scope.cityname = $scope.cityname || "";`.

I  don't understand why you would do this though, since `""` and `undefined` both evaluate to false.

Comment: well, i am passing values from mvc variable to directive ':cityname="@defaultCity" statecode="@defaultStateCode">'

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a scope isolation issue.

What's happening is that your directive will populate its scope using three values from the controller and since you're using `@` in scope isolation, your directive will take the values from the controller and bind it one way, whether they are defined or not.

Since binding is one way, changes in the controller will reflect into the directive but changes to these values in the directive will not reflect in the controller. This means that if you change the value in the directive, like set cityName to `Islamabad`, then controller will not know of this change and it will keep the old value with it, which could very well be undefined if the variable was never initialized.

If you want two way binding then use `=` instead of `@`. This way changes in the directive to these variables will be reflected in the controller.

Link to scope isolation article: [Creating custom AngularJS directives](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope)

Comment: still it is coming as undefined, !!

Comment: I see, controllers get executed before directives, perhaps you are checking for something inside the controller before the directive has had a chance to execute and change it?